# angularjs checkbox item in array

Tags: angularjs

I am using a mix of ASP.Net MVC and AngularJS in my Application, and am fairly new to both. For various reasons, I have decided to create a form using MVC and then load data and bind to the form elements using AngularJS.

There is a challenge with two items, that I kind of found a solution to, but not sure if it's optimal. I was eager to hear if there is a better way to do this.

In my AngularJS Controller, I have a Scope where a part looks like this:

```
{
   (...)
   Barriers: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
   (...)
   BarrierComments: [
      { BarrierGroup: 'x', Comment: 'Some text here' },
      { BarrierGroup: 'y', Comment: 'Some other text here' },
      { BarrierGroup: 'x', Comment: 'Some third text here' }
   ]
   (...)
}
```

Now, in the generated form, I have two items that I'd like to bind:
1) CheckBoxes that should bind and add/remove items from the Barriers array
2) TextAreas that should each edit the Comment inside the BarrierComments

(I know this could be easier done with using ng-repeat, or maybe by changing the model a bit. However, my world is a bit more complex, and I still want to find the best solution)

At the MVC part, I generate checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="Barriers.indexOf('a') > -1" ng-click="toggleBarrier('a')" />
```

(The toggleBarrier function will add or remove an item from the Barrier array)

TextAreas are generated like this:

```
<textarea ng-model="(BarrierComments | filter:{BarrierGroup:'x'})[0].Comment"></textarea>
```

Note that a...e and x...z are in fact Guids, just shortened for readability. These are also being configured in a database, so they are not fixed values.

My question is: Is there a more elegant way to make the Controls bind to this data? I am particulary unhappy With the TextArea which will fail if my model is missing an item in the BarrierComments array...